# DirectX11 ClearRenderTargetViewback with transparent buffer?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to create a window that uses directx to draw **opaque** content on top of a **transparent** view (i.e. the desktop shows through). With DirectX11 I'm trying to do the following, but it's not making the background transparent. In fact, any opacity value I put in gives me the exact same results.

What I'm doing:

```
float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffer, color);
```

Working repro code (main.cpp):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Winmm.lib")

#include <d3d11.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler.lib")

#include <dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Dwmapi.lib")


// Globals
IDXGISwapChain *swapChain;
ID3D11Device *device;
ID3D11DeviceContext *deviceContext;
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backBuffer;
ID3D11InputLayout *inputLayout;            // the pointer to the input layout
ID3D11VertexShader *vertexShader;               // the pointer to the vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader *pixelShader;                // the pointer to the pixel shader
ID3D11Buffer *vertexBuffer;                // the pointer to the vertex buffer

void InitializeDirectX(HWND hWnd);
void LoadTriangle();

struct Vertex {
    float x, y, z;
    float color[4];
};

// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
                       // close the application entirely
                       PostQuitMessage(0);
                       return 0;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// Globals
const LPCWSTR ClassName = L"className";


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    // the handle for the window, filled by a function
    HWND hWnd;
    // this struct holds information for the window class
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    // Pick out window size
    int windowHeight = 400;
    int windowWidth = 400;

    // clear out the window class for use
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    // fill in the struct with the needed information
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;

    // register the window class
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Window style
    DWORD exStyle = WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST;
    DWORD style = WS_POPUP;

    // create the window and use the result as the handle
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        exStyle,        // extended styles
        ClassName,    // name of the window class
        L"TestOverlay",   // title of the window
        style,    // window style
        0,    // x-position of the window
        0,    // y-position of the window
        400,    // width of the window
        400,    // height of the window
        NULL,    // we have no parent window, NULL
        NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
        hInstance,    // application handle
        NULL);    // used with multiple windows, NULL

    // display the window on the screen
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    SetWindowPos(hWnd,
        HWND_TOPMOST,
        0, 0,
        windowWidth, windowHeight,
        SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

    // Show the window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Make the window transparent
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_ALPHA | LWA_COLORKEY);

    // NOTE: If I uncomment DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea then it becomes transparent, otherwise its a black screen
    MARGINS dwmMargin = { -1 };
    //DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &dwmMargin);

    // DirectX
    InitializeDirectX(hWnd);
    LoadTriangle();

    // enter the main loop:
    MSG msg;
    BOOL gotMessage;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            // DirectX stuff
            float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
            deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffer, color);

            // Draw triangle
            UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
            UINT offset = 0;
            deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
            deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
            deviceContext->Draw(3, 0);

            swapChain->Present(0, 0);

        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}


void InitializeDirectX(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapChain,
        &device,
        NULL,
        &deviceContext);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backBuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backBuffer, NULL);

    // Set the viewport size
    RECT cRect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &cRect);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = cRect.right - cRect.left;
    viewport.Height = cRect.bottom - cRect.top;

    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);


    // Initialize pipeline stuff
    ID3D10Blob *VS, *PS;

    // compile shader
    D3DCompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, &VS, 0);
    D3DCompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, &PS, 0);

    // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
    device->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &vertexShader);
    device->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pixelShader);

    deviceContext->VSSetShader(vertexShader, 0, 0);
    deviceContext->PSSetShader(pixelShader, 0, 0);

    // create input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };

    device->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &inputLayout);
    deviceContext->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout);

}


void LoadTriangle()
{
    // create a triangle using the VERTEX struct
    Vertex OurVertices[] =
    {
    { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },
    { 0.45f, -0.5, 0.0f, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },
    { -0.45f, -0.5f, 0.0f, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }
    };


    // create the vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex)* 3;             // size is the VERTEX struct * 3
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;       // use as a vertex buffer
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer

    device->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &vertexBuffer);       // create the buffer


    // copy the vertices into the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    deviceContext->Map(vertexBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
    memcpy(ms.pData, OurVertices, sizeof(OurVertices));                 // copy the data
    deviceContext->Unmap(vertexBuffer, NULL);                                      // unmap the buffer
}
```

Shader file (shaders.shader):

```
struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = position;
    output.color = color;

    return output;
}

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

If you uncomment the DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea call on line 119ish, then it gets the effect I'm looking for. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the same effect without the use of dwm (for reasons I won't go into).

Any ideas?

Edit: Added full source code of working example. Found out that if I make a call to DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea, then I get the effect I want. But I'd still like to know if its possible to do it without using dwm apis.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a Window transparent with DirectX only, The following code only clear the background color to black.

```
float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

To achieve transparent effect of your window, you need to involve some win32 stuff, SetLayeredWindowAttributes is your choice.

```
// Show the window
ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );
UpdateWindow( hWnd );

SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED) ;
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 100, LWA_ALPHA);
```

**UPDATE:**

Workable code draw nothing but make the window transparent in green color.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Winmm.lib")

#include <d3d11.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler.lib")

#include <dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Dwmapi.lib")


// Globals
IDXGISwapChain *swapChain;
ID3D11Device *device;
ID3D11DeviceContext *deviceContext;
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backBuffer;

void InitializeDirectX(HWND hWnd);

// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            // close the application entirely
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

// Globals
const LPCWSTR ClassName = L"className";


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    // fill in the struct with the needed information
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;

    // register the window class
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // create the window and use the result as the handle
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,        // extended styles
        ClassName,    // name of the window class
        L"TestOverlay",   // title of the window
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    // window style
        0,    // x-position of the window
        0,    // y-position of the window
        400,    // width of the window
        400,    // height of the window
        NULL,    // we have no parent window, NULL
        NULL,    // we aren't using menus, NULL
        hInstance,    // application handle
        NULL);    // used with multiple windows, NULL

    // display the window on the screen
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Make the window transparent
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED) ;
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 128, LWA_ALPHA);

    // DirectX
    InitializeDirectX(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:
    MSG msg;
    BOOL gotMessage;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            // DirectX stuff
            float color[4] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
            deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffer, color);
            swapChain->Present(0, 0);
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}


void InitializeDirectX(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                    // windowed/full-screen mode

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapChain,
        &device,
        NULL,
        &deviceContext);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backBuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backBuffer, NULL);

    // Set the viewport size
    RECT cRect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &cRect);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = cRect.right - cRect.left;
    viewport.Height = cRect.bottom - cRect.top;

    deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've already done that. However, for some reason the transparency color key specified in SetLayeredWindowAttributes is not working with my DirectX clear color.

Comment: it works for me here, if you still have problem, paste full code please.

Comment: I managed to get it working by adding a call to DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea. Did you have to do that as well? I'd prefer not to use Dwm for what I'm doing, so if your solution works without that call then I'll try to condense my code into a smaller repro and post the entire thing.

Comment: No, I didn't use Dwm, I just use what I post above.

Comment: I added full code of a working repro. Thanks for your help so far zdd

Comment: You should not use 255 in [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx), that's make the window opaque.

Comment: I have edit your code, remove all unnecessary code, draw nothing, just make the window transparent, please see my UPDATE and try it.

Comment: Ohhh I should have been more clear on what I wanted. In my example with dwm, the triangle is 100% opaque, while the rest of the screen region is 100% transparent. In your answer, the entire screen is at 50% transparency, so if I were to draw a triangle then that triangle would also be at 50% transparency.