# C++ DirectX 11 Transparency

Tags: c++, directx

How to make transparent background in DirectX 11 C++?

```
float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

`deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(backBuffer, color);`

this doesn't work

Comment: Question has been asked before with workable code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23454462/1235106